# Laravel - Auth User returns null

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm trying to redirect the user to a 'dashboard' page after he has registered. However, when I dump and die the auth()-user(), it returns null. It should display the information of the authenticated user from my database.

Register Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function NavRegPage(){
        return view('regPage');
    }

    public function store(Request  $request){
        $data = request()->validate([
            'username' => ['required', 'max:20'],
            'password' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:20' ],
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'url' => ['required', 'url'],
            'dob' => ['required']
        ]);

        $user = new User();
        $user->username = request('username');
        $user->password = request('password');
        $user->email = request('email');
        $user->url = request('url');
        $user->dob = request('dob');
        $user->save();

        auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));
        return redirect()->route('dash');
    }
```

Dash controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashController extends Controller
{
        public function index(){
            dd(auth()->user());
        }
}
```

Web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController as RegisterController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashController as DashController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'NavRegPage']) ->name('register');
Route::get('dash', [\App\Http\Controllers\DashController::class, 'index']) ->name('dash');
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::post('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'store'])->name('register');
```

I want the dd to show me the authenticated user information so I can continue with my work.
Thank you

Comment: you need to apply `auth`  middleware in `Route::get('dash')->middleware('auth')`

Comment: Can you show me where I'm really new to Laravel

Answer (score 0):

in web.php

```php
Route::get('dash', [\App\Http\Controllers\DashController::class, 'index']) ->name('dash')->middleware('auth');
```

apply `->middleware('auth');` then your `auth()` will work on that controller

Comment: Adding middleware auth gives me this error;
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [login] not defined.

Comment: yeah it is correct i is not login to it redirect to login page and you remove login page so

Comment: So how do I change it, I don't have anything mentioned to redirect to 'login', where can I change it to 'dashboard' page?

Comment: `dashboard` is a protected url right why you will redirect to dashboard if user is not login

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is, once the register form is filled, and all the form data is saved in my MySQL database, I want to take the user to the dashboard page where he'll be logged in as he just registered. For that I need to authenticate the user using auth()->user

Comment: then `auth()->user` this will return user when it is login otherwise it will show null

Comment: I don't think my question is clear, nevermind. I'll try something else. Thanks anyways!